# vba dictionary of arrays at the run time

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

How to create dictionary of arrays? I want to store the data as follows:

`trainingdict.add empname , softskills(t1, t2, t3, t4)`  [an array of softskills training for an given emp]

`trainingdict.add empname , techskills(t1, t2, t3, t4)`   [an array of techskills training for an given emp]

For now i have concatenated the training's against an given emp by joining them by ";" and using "|" to segregate between softskills (towards left of pipe delimiter) and techskills (towards right of pipe delimiter) which is as follows:

`trainingdict.add empname , t1;t2;t3;t4 | t1;t2;t3;t4`

This is working but requires additonal loops to split through delimiters and access the values.

Comment: `trainingdict.add empname , Array(softskills(t1, t2, t3, t4), techskills(t1, t2, t3, t4))`

Answer (score 0):

why didn't you try to add variants as values?

```
set d= new dictionary
v = make_variant(x,y,z)
d.Add empname, v
```

This will work as:

```
d("employee")(0) 'x
d("employee")(1) ... 'y
```

Answer (score 0):

a way of keeping track easily of what is happening is using `Type` :

```
Option Explicit

Type SkillType
    techskills() as string
    SoftSkills() as string
end type



sub test
Dim Temp as Skilltype
Dim Arr1()
Dim Arr2()
'... populate arrays
set Temp = new Skilltype
Temp.techskills=Arr1
Temp.Softskills=Arr2
'populate dictionary
set trainingdict(empname)=Temp
end sub
```

Note: untested, but it's good reference